# Applying a (Gaussian) Filter on an Image in Parallel - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, parallel-processing

I created the following (MATLAB) function to apply Gaussian Filter blur on an image:

```
function [ mBlurredImage ] = ApplyGaussianBlur( mInputImage, gaussianKernelStd, stdToRadiusFactor )

gaussianBlurRadius  = ceil(stdToRadiusFactor * gaussianKernelStd); % Imitating Photoshop - See Reference

vGaussianKernel = exp(-([-gaussianBlurRadius:gaussianBlurRadius] .^ 2) / (2 * gaussianKernelStd * gaussianKernelStd));
vGaussianKernel = vGaussianKernel / sum(vGaussianKernel);

mInputImagePadded   = padarray(mInputImage, [gaussianBlurRadius, gaussianBlurRadius], 'replicate', 'both');

mBlurredImage = conv2(vGaussianKernel, vGaussianKernel.', mInputImagePadded, 'valid');


end
```

I'm trying to find the best approach to create a parallel version of it.
I want to find a method /strategy which applies to OpenMP as well.

I tried padding the image, then divide it to 4 sections and apply the blur on each.
Then I gathered all pieces.
Here's the code:

```
function [ mBlurredImage ] = ApplyGaussianBlurParallel( mInputImage, gaussianKernelStd, stdToRadiusFactor, numThreads )

numRows = size(mInputImage, 1);
numCols = size(mInputImage, 2);

% mBlurredImage = zeros(numRows, numCols);

gaussianKernelRadius  = ceil(stdToRadiusFactor * gaussianKernelStd); % Imitating Photoshop - See Reference

vGaussianKernel = exp(-([-gaussianKernelRadius:gaussianKernelRadius] .^ 2) / (2 * gaussianKernelStd * gaussianKernelStd));
vGaussianKernel = vGaussianKernel / sum(vGaussianKernel);

numRowsPadded = numRows + (2 * gaussianKernelRadius);
numColsPadded = numCols + (2 * gaussianKernelRadius);

mInputImagePadded   = padarray(mInputImage, [gaussianKernelRadius, gaussianKernelRadius], 'replicate', 'both');

vColIdxImageBlock = round(linspace(1, numCols, (numThreads + 1)));

vFirstColIdxImageBlock = vColIdxImageBlock(1:numThreads);
% Going form Image Axis to Padded Image Axis
vFirstColIdxImagePaddedBlock = vFirstColIdxImageBlock + gaussianKernelRadius;
% Adding Pixels to the left
vFirstColIdxImagePaddedBlock = vFirstColIdxImagePaddedBlock - gaussianKernelRadius;

vLastColIdxImageBlock = vColIdxImageBlock(2:(numThreads + 1));
% Going form Image Axis to Padded Image Axis
vLastColIdxImagePaddedBlock = vLastColIdxImageBlock + gaussianKernelRadius;
% Adding Pixels to the right
vLastColIdxImagePaddedBlock = vLastColIdxImagePaddedBlock + gaussianKernelRadius;

vRowsIdxImage = 1:numRows;
vRowsImagePadded = 1:numRowsPadded;

cImageBlock             = cell(numThreads, 1);
cImageBlockProcessed    = cell(numThreads, 1);

for iBlockIdx = 1:numThreads
    firstColIdxImagePaddedBlock    = vFirstColIdxImagePaddedBlock(iBlockIdx);
    lastColIdxImagePaddedBlock     = vLastColIdxImagePaddedBlock(iBlockIdx);
    vColsIdxImagePadded = [firstColIdxImagePaddedBlock:lastColIdxImagePaddedBlock];

    cImageBlock{iBlockIdx} =  mInputImagePadded(vRowsImagePadded, vColsIdxImagePadded);
end

parfor iBlockIdx = 1:numThreads
   cImageBlockProcessed{iBlockIdx} = conv2(vGaussianKernel, vGaussianKernel.', cImageBlock{iBlockIdx}, 'valid');
end

mBlurredImage = zeros(numRows, numCols);

for iBlockIdx = 1:numThreads
    firstColIdxImageBlock    = vFirstColIdxImageBlock(iBlockIdx);
    lastColIdxImageBlock     = vLastColIdxImageBlock(iBlockIdx);
    vColsIdxImage = [firstColIdxImageBlock:lastColIdxImageBlock];

    mBlurredImage(vRowsIdxImage, vColsIdxImage) = cImageBlockProcessed{iBlockIdx};
end


end
```

I also created the following script to analyze the performance:

```
% `ApplyGaussianBlurParallel` Test Case
clear();

vInputImageSize = [720, 1280, 1920, 2560];
numIterations   = 20;

vRunTimeParallelGaussianBlur    = zeros(numIterations, length(vInputImageSize));
vRunTimeSerialGaussianBlur      = zeros(numIterations, length(vInputImageSize));

gaussianKernelStd   = 10;
stdToRadiusFactor   = 3.5;
numThreads          = 4;

for iImageSizeIdx = 1:length(vInputImageSize);
    imageSize = vInputImageSize(iImageSizeIdx);

    mInputImage = randn(imageSize, 'single');

    maxNumCompThreads(1);

    for iIter = 1:numIterations
        hTimeStart = tic();
        mBlurredImage1 = ApplyGaussianBlur(mInputImage, gaussianKernelStd, stdToRadiusFactor);
        vRunTimeSerialGaussianBlur(iIter, iImageSizeIdx) = toc(hTimeStart);
    end

    maxNumCompThreads(numThreads);

    for iIter = 1:numIterations
        hTimeStart = tic();
        mBlurredImage1 = ApplyGaussianBlurParallel(mInputImage, gaussianKernelStd, stdToRadiusFactor, numThreads);
        vRunTimeParallelGaussianBlur(iIter, iImageSizeIdx) = toc(hTimeStart);
    end

end

vRunTimeParallelGaussianBlurMean    = mean(vRunTimeParallelGaussianBlur);
vRunTimeParallelGaussianBlurStd     = std(vRunTimeParallelGaussianBlur);
vRunTimeParallelGaussianBlurMedian  = median(vRunTimeParallelGaussianBlur);

vRunTimeSerialGaussianBlurMean    = mean(vRunTimeSerialGaussianBlur);
vRunTimeSerialGaussianBlurStd     = std(vRunTimeSerialGaussianBlur);
vRunTimeSerialGaussianBlurMedian  = median(vRunTimeSerialGaussianBlur);

figure();
plot(vInputImageSize, [vRunTimeParallelGaussianBlurMean(:), vRunTimeSerialGaussianBlurMean(:)], ...
    'LineStyle', 'none', 'Marker', 'o');
title('Mean Runtime');
legend({['Parallel'], ['Serial']});

figure();
plot(vInputImageSize, [vRunTimeParallelGaussianBlurMedian(:), vRunTimeSerialGaussianBlurMedian(:)], ...
    'LineStyle', 'none', 'Marker', 'o');
title('Median Runtime');
legend({['Parallel'], ['Serial']});
```

Yet what I get is:

[image: Mean of Run Time]
[image: Median of Run Time]

Namely, I can't make it efficient enough.
Can anyone think on a better more efficient approach or doing it better?

Thank You.

Comment: how big is your image? My guess is it's small. For a small image the overhead involved in splitting and recombining an image as well as doing all the parallel initialization work maybe outweigh the benefits. Maybe try with a much larger image and see what happens. Like I said, it's just a guess

Comment: Hi... You can see the size above. I went from small to large.

Comment: my apologies, I didn't realize the x-axis was image size. Sorry I can't be of more help, good luck

Answer (score 2):

At some point you are mixing up number of Threads in your matlab process with the number of computation workers the parallel computing toolbox is using.

`maxNumCompThreads` sets the number of threads each matlab process is allowed to use. This is not associated to the parallel computing toolbox.

`parpool` or `matlabpool` sets the number of workers (individual processes) which process jobs generated via one of the parallel computing toolbox functions like `parfor`.

The `ApplyGaussianBlurParallel` needs the number of workers, not the number of threads which you are currently passing.

Fixing this I got slightly better results, but parallel computing was still slower. I totally removed `maxNumCompThreads`, don't see a reason to use it here.

The most efficient way is probably using your GPU:

```
function [ mBlurredImage ] = ApplyGaussianBlur( mInputImage, 

gaussianKernelStd, stdToRadiusFactor )

gaussianBlurRadius  = ceil(stdToRadiusFactor * gaussianKernelStd); % Imitating Photoshop - See Reference

vGaussianKernel = exp(-([-gaussianBlurRadius:gaussianBlurRadius] .^ 2) / (2 * gaussianKernelStd * gaussianKernelStd));
vGaussianKernel = vGaussianKernel / sum(vGaussianKernel);

mInputImagePadded   = padarray(mInputImage, [gaussianBlurRadius, gaussianBlurRadius], 'replicate', 'both');
GvGaussianKernel=gpuArray(vGaussianKernel);
GmInputImagePadded=gpuArray(mInputImagePadded);
mBlurredImage = conv2(GvGaussianKernel, GvGaussianKernel.', GmInputImagePadded, 'valid');


end
```

Same benchmark (Core i5-4690 4x 3500MHz / GT730):
[image]

Comment: as you can see above, I limit the number of threads for `ApplyGaussianBlur` to be 1.

Comment: I'm after to most efficient way to partition an image for parallel computation. I created one approach, are there any better?

Comment: @Drazick Provided another alternative using GPU

Comment: It seems I can't efficiently tell the parallel part each of them has its own independent section to work on. That's the problem.